# Is it possible to use quad-channels reverbs in Web Audio Api? (make stereo sound)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, web-midi

is it possible to be used in channelized sound quad-reverb types? And use the 4-channel reverbs (two stereo files: LR and RL).Does Web Audio Api support quad mode?
I use Web Midi Api for work. And my scheme at this moment allows me connect one reverb (one file) to one channel, another reverb (second file) to another channel. (I use splitter for this). I have interesting output sound. But the target not in this. 
The folder with my reverbs and image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ylL3.jpg), how it have to see. Responses are my reverb on an image.
Please, anybody, help me understand what I need to include in scheme, for my goal.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx9T82nwlRwGQzZSNVlEUDl0OGM&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want, but if the examples in https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#Convolution-channel-configurations don't include what you want to do, you'll have to use either mono or stereo convolver nodes arranged appropriately to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, "true" stereo  exactly what I want

Comment: Can you, please, help me one more time? I have done true stereo as in scheme, but my tester told me, that convolver from left chanell heard as mono, on both channels left reverb response similar.

Comment: Connect note to preset
https://jsfiddle.net/Oxana/33yt8ay2/. Connect preset to sampler:https://jsfiddle.net/Oxana/m2a48rd4/. I use backbone.js for my work

Comment: Can anybody answer, must all buffers for convolvers in scheme https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#Convolution-channel-configurations be different?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  A `ConvolverNode` only has one buffer.  The buffer can have 1, 2, or 4 channels in it.  The contents of the channels can be anything, including all different or all the same.

Comment: I have only 2 sound files(reverbs) to do true stereo, but in scheme I have four ConvolverNode, when I use 1 file (decoding to buffer) for convolverNode1 and convolverNode2 buffers, 2 file -  for convolverNode3, convolverNode4 buffers I have mono effect. Example: load left-channel sound, apply left reverb to it - we will hear (dry gain)clean sound from left side only - and it is ok, but response from reverb in both sides the same - it is wrong. I want to hear response that effect as in init sound file (left reverb sound from left, but then flew to right side creating wide stereo effect).